# Auto Rotate while switching between View Controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a problem in programming. I have two view controllers. The first runs only in landscape left / right, the other runs only in portrait. If I switching between the views the orientation do not change automaticly. Only when I turn the device the orientation is changing. After that the orientation is fixed. Is it possible to change the orientation automaticly when I switching between the controllers?

As Example when I press the BackButton in the Landscape View Controller and it switch to the Portrait View Controller that the orientation automaticly switch from Landscape to Portrait?

Sorry for my bad english, it is not my native language.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Code for Portrait  in Second View.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

}
```

Try the following Code for Landscape  in First View.

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape];

    }
```

Comment: I believe the undocumented `setOrientation` call only works in the simulator.  On a real device, you can't really programmatically set the orientation.  The user has to physically rotate the device.

Comment: I got an error: " No visible @interface for 'UIDevice' declares the selector 'setOrientation' "

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0):

```
if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
{
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);
}
 else
{
  self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024);
}
```

----use this code where you want to change---